# Where is "su" addon package for rooting LineageOS 17 and newer?

Tags: root-access, lineageos, android-10

On the current [LineageOS Extras Download](https://download.lineageos.org/extras), you can see `su` packages for versions up to LineageOS version 16. Where are the newer packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This functionality was discontinued.](https://www.xda-developers.com/lineageos-dropping-superuser-addonsu-implementation-favor-magisk-manager/) The de facto method of achieving root in newer LineageOS releases is [Magisk.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magisk_(software))